# When using WebFont loader, how to hardcode the css?

Tags: javascript, css, google-webfonts

To load a font with WebFont, I do as they suggest here: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader

```
WebFontConfig = {
    custom: { families: ['font1', 'font2', 'font3'],
    urls: [ 'stylesheets/fonts.css' ] },
    loading: function(){
        console.log('loaded');
    },
    inactive: function(){
        console.log('not loaded');
    }
};
WebFont.load(WebFontConfig);
```

But this mean that the broswer wait the download of the css file before it starts loading the fonts.The css is just a few lines of code and i don't see why I could not paste it directly in the js.

Anyone knowes how to achieve that ?

Comment: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ux-tutorials/quick-tip-avoid-fout-by-adding-a-web-font-preloader/

Comment: Nice tut, but they still load an external css before loading the fonts ; this is what I want to avoid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not possible ; the detection starts when the download of the css is done.

Answer (score 0):

How about download the font and use @font-face  in your CSS, like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gang-of-Three";
  src: url("fonts/gangofthree.ttf")
  }
```

Comment: Because, I need to know when the fonts are loaded. The window.onload should trigger when everything is loaded including the fonts, but doesn't everywhere.